# Ancestor index or global index?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I have an entity that represents a relationship between two entity groups but the entity belongs to one of the groups. However, my queries for this data are going to be mostly with the other entity group. To support the queries I see I have two choices a) Create a global index that has the other entity group key as prefix b) Move the entity into the other entity group and create ancestor index.

I saw a presentation which mentioned that ancestor indexes map internally to a separate table per entity group while there is a single table for the global index. That makes me feel that ancestors are better than using global indexes which includes the ancestor keys as prefix for this specific use case where I will always be querying in the context of some ancestor key.

Looking for guidance on this in terms of performance, storage characteristics, transaction latency and any other architectural considerations to make the final call.

Answer (score 0):

From what I was able to found I would say it depends on the of the type of work you'll be doing. looked at [this docs](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/best-practices) and it suggest you Avoid writing to an entity group more than once per second. Also indexing a property could result in increased latency. Also it states that  If you need strong consistency for your queries, use an ancestor query, in that docs there are many advice's on how to avoid latency and other issues. it should help you on taking a call.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a 3rd option which is to have another entity denormalized into the other entity group and have ancestor queries on it. This allows me to efficiently query data for either of the entity groups. Since I was using transactions already, denormalizing wouldn't cause any inconsistencies and everything seems to work well.